# How to hide zoom controller from Android Studio Bumblebee?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-emulator, android-studio-bumblebee

On running Android emulator in latest Android Studio Bumbleebee, I'm seeing these controls on top of it. How can I hide or remove them?

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In emulator section's setting icon you can see the options of "Show Zoom Controls". Using that you can enable/disable the zoom controls.
[image]

Comment: How to hide permanently? So that, next time not enable automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Click the gear icon "show options menu" in top right of emulator pane, then toggle "show zoom controls"